# generate warning when button click odoo website

Tags: odoo, odoo-website

I want to generate a warning near ADDTOCART when the ADDTOCART button clicked on odoo website.

[image]

XML file:

```
<t t-if="website.get_promo_code_error(delete=False)">
 <div class="card bg-danger text-white mt16">
   <div class="card-header clearfix">
     <span class="float-left"><t t-esc="website.get_promo_code_error()" /></span>
   </div>
  </div>
</t>
```

Controler:

```
request.session['error_promo_code'] = "Can not add"
return request.redirect("/shop/product/%s" % product.id)
```

model:

```
def get_promo_code_error(self, delete=True):
    error = request.session.get('error_promo_code')
        if error and delete:
            request.session.pop('error_promo_code')
        return error
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Odoo** there is a `default` **feature** which provides on the website.

> **Goto** Product -> Ecommerce tab -> there you find field **Availability**-> select this option
> **Show inventory below a threshold and prevent sales if not enough stock**

It will allow you to add the **Availability Threshold**, Add your product stock value like 10.

When you go on the webshop and add more than **10 qty** for the same **product** it will trigger the **message** near the `add to cart` button.